# ASN parser for TCL

Tags: tcl, asn.1

Well, the title pretty much says it all.
Does anyone knows any good (or any at all) Asn library for Tcl?
I need that it will be statically linked library.

thanks.

Answer (score 3):

There's an ASN.1 encoder/decoder package in tcllib called `asn`: http://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/doc/tcllib-1-18/embedded/www/tcllib/files/modules/asn/asn.html

If you do any serious amount of tcl programming especially if you do networking stuff you should install tcllib. Most big projects have dependencies on packages provided by tcllib so you may already have tcllib installed.

Comment: how do i install it?

Comment: i tried to use it before but i had problem with the makefile

Comment: @itayb: Depends on your OS. On Mac it's installed by default because Apple use some tools that rely on tcl. On Debian based Linux do a `apt-cache search` for tcllib. On RedHat based Linux do a `yum search` for tcllib. On Windows if you use ActiveTcl then I think it should be already installed. If none of the above you can download the tar/zip file and install manually. I'm not sure how to install manually I'm afraid. Read the wiki or google

Comment: ok, i found in one of the tcl libraries that we have a file named asn.tcl, with the same function as the one in the link Nir Levy gave, i have copied it to the library of the tcl we compile with but i don't know how to call the functions of this file in the c code. we let the user to define tcl script and use it on the fly, but i have no idea how to insert those functions to the script.

Comment: i will ask it a different way. if i have a tcl function, how do i call it from c/c++ and pass parameter to the function.
i found some example but not with parameters.
thanks

Comment: a different question - does anyone knows a good c/c++ asn1 library for c that i can incorporate easily into my project?
thanks.